# How to remove duplicate rows and keep one in an Access database?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, duplicates

[image: I got too many entry like this in my database]

I need to remove duplicate rows in my Access database, does anyone have generic query to do this? As I have this problem with multiple tables

Comment: This is what would be referred to as an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)". The first question should be "where are all these duplicates coming from?"  What's causing this issue?

Comment: This problem is caused because of Local and Server Sync Functionality implemented in windows application and I have the only brief idea about it.

Comment: The database is stored in local and server both side. When connectivity finds send data from LocalDB to the server DB same server DB send to local DB.

Comment: You can start by using the Find duplicates query wizard. That will generate a lot of the required SQL for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to do,

1. *Determine what the criteria are for a unique record* - what is the list of columns where two, or more, records would be considered duplicates, e.g. JobbID and HisGuid
2. *Decide what you want to do with the duplicate records* - do you want to hard delete them, or set the IsDeleted flag that you have on the table

Once you've determined the criteria that you want to use for uniqueness you then need to pick *1* record from each group of duplicates to retain. A query along the lines of:

```
SELECT  MAX(ID)
FROM    MyTable
GROUP
BY      JobbID, HisGuid
```

Will give you (and I've assumed that the `ID` column is an auto-increment/identity column that is unique across all records in the table) the *highest* value for each group of records where `JobbID` and `HisGuid` are both the same. You could use `MIN(ID)` if you want, it's up to you - you just need to pick ONE record from each group **to keep**.

Assuming that you want to set the `IsDeleted` flag on the records you don't want to keep, you can then incorporate this into an update query:

```
UPDATE  MyTable
SET     IsDeleted = 1
WHERE   ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT  MAX(ID)
    FROM    MyTable
    GROUP
    BY  JobbID, HisGuid
)
```

This takes the result of the query that retrieves the *highest IDs* and uses it to say *set `IsDeleted` to 1 for all the records where the ID isn't the highest ID for each group of records where `JobbID` and `HisGuid` are the same*.

The only part I can't help you with is *running* these queries in Access as I don't have it installed on the PC I'm using right now and my memory is a bit rusty regarding how/where to run arbitrary queries.

Comment: I want to hard delete from my database.

Comment: do you have any other solution for it? HisGuid Is unique field and ID is a primary key.

Comment: Hi @UnknownUser, I'm not sure what you mean by "any other solution", you should be able to take the *principles* I've given and the *example of using those principles* and apply them to whatever the unique fields are. In this instance it sounds like you'd just be removing `JobbID` from the GROUP BY clause? If you want to delete then instead of UPDATE Mytable/SET it'll be DELETE MyTable